# Printing Value in Excel

Tags: excel

Hello guys I have a question for you,

How do I print a month only lets say

Cell A1 = 02/04/1992
I want to print the month only of cell A1 so
A2 = 02
How do I print the Month only ? into a cell?

Comment: You cannot change the question after you posted one. If you have a different question, post a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in A2 :

```
=MONTH(A1)
```

It works fine

Comment: That will only display the month? I want to display the Row number

Comment: You change the question  !

Comment: What question did I change?

Comment: @ZAhmed I have rolled back his original question.   Changing the question once answer is recieved is not the right way to do

Answer (score 0):

Use `MONTH` function, i.e.: `=MONTH(A1)`. Refer to: [MONTH function](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-month-function)

Put these values in B column:

```
      A          B
1  05/1/2014     5
2  06/1/2014     6
3  07/1/2014     7
4  08/1/2014     8
5  09/1/2014     9
```

Then, in `C1` place formula:

`=CELL("address", INDEX(A1:B5, MATCH(6, B1:B5, 0), 1))`

It will display address of a cell, in this case `A2`. You can write `column` or `row` instead of `address` in above formula to get column or row of a cell respectively.

Comment: that would only display the month?

Comment: See edited answer. To get more details about used functions, google them or refer to Microsoft documentation :)